# How to use setHoverCardPresenterSelector in ListRowPresenter leanback

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ListRowPresenter.html#sethovercardpresenterselector) said:

> Sets the PresenterSelector used for showing a select object in a hover
>   card.

But I found no example of how to use and even what exactly it means. Anyone has extra info? Currently by examining source code I guess it has something to do with [HorizontalHoverCardSwitcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/HorizontalHoverCardSwitcher) But need more help!